# Heroku open and get 502 error with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku

Just checked my logs and I'm getting this error:

```
2015-12-21T17:41:06.304648+00:00 app[web.1]: [Mon Dec 21 17:41:06.303907 2015] [autoindex:error] [pid 100:tid 139688442590976] [client 10.147.38.224:15662] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive.
```

What is going on?

Comment: can you provide a little more context?

Comment: Sure. In my terminal - typed heroku open to launch my app and I got a 403 error FORBIDDEN (NOT 502) using Heroku logs I came across the above error.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with you not setting up your Heroku environ properly...have you read through all the documentation? Do you have a Procfile setup in your app root?

> Use a Procfile, a text file in the root directory of your application, to explicitly declare what command should be executed to start your app.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#define-a-procfile